# A or an? Should I consider the phrase after it?

Tags: word-choice, articles, indefinite-article

Briefly, which one is correct?

> A, again, beautiful home ...

or

> An, again, beautiful home ...

Comment: Neither of the phrases makes any sense. But if you are asking which indefinite article to use, the rule is that the choice of **a** or **an** depends on **sound, not spelling**.
https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/the-indefinite-article-a-and-an

Comment: You should consider "again, a beautiful home".  The noun phrase "a beautiful home" is coherent as it stands, but it doesn't remain coherent with that interruption.

Comment: Or _a once again beautiful home_ if it has been restored to its former beauty.

Comment: Or *a beautiful home again*. Parenthetical text should have no bearing on the main text that surrounds it. But, in this case, it will either sound strange one way, or not follow that rule the other way. You're left with a construction that doesn't work no matter how you look at it; so, don't use it.